# polymorphism + interfaces in php

Tags: php, oop, interface, polymorphism

Consider you have the this code: (result will be "works")

```
interface iUser { }
interface iRepository {
    function save(iUser $user);
}

class User implements iUser {

}

class Repository implements iRepository {
    # works with iUser but why not with User? User implements iUser :)
    function save(iUser $user) {

        if(!$user instanceof User)
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException('...');

        echo 'works!';
    }
}

$user = new User();
$repo = new Repository();
$repo->save($user);
```

this example works because User implements iUser.
if i implement the save function this way:

```
function save(User $user) {
```

it fails with the message
    Declaration of Repository::save() must be compatible with that of iRepository::save()

from my point of view this isn't true. User is fully compactible with iUser.

1. why php doesnt support this? is there a real reason or is it more like a bug in the language?
2. Where is the difference in typechecking between a typehint and instanceof?
3. how does other languages handels this?

Answer (score 0):

You have to change iUser to User in the save method in Interface iRepository too.
A interface method must always be compatible with the implementation method. That's all, no language issue or similar... In other (compiled) languages (e.g. C#, Java) you would get an error before compilation.

Comment: i dont want to change this in the repository. the repository is just an interface and doesnt know something about the implementation user. but the User is an iUser. so from my point of view there is no reason why this shouldnt work.

Comment: that's right, but you're not changing the implementation, you're changing the construct. the implementation is the code inside the method stub.

Comment: i don't understand what you mean. i change the implementation, the repository class. i don't change the construct (interface).

Comment: when you have an interface method like public function test(Something s); you have to implement the method stub in the concrete inherited class the same way: public function test(Something s) { //implementation }. The "Something" must be the same!

Comment: the idea of an interface is to make sure that the the api is compactibe. In this example the User is fully compactibe to the Interface iUser. So User is a iUser. The "Something" is the same :)

Comment: not really, because you're implementing to an interface. ;)